# Showing one feature with two unique values as one symbol in ArcMap legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, arcgis-10.4

I am working in ArcMap 10.4. I have one feature that has two unique values, one is "simple fill" blue the other value is "10% simple hatch". I need to show the 2 values in the map but would like to only show the solid hatch in the legend. I know I could separate the feature and then just remove one from the legend.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK legends act on the layer level, not the symbol class level (other than using view extent option to show classes). You are right, you can copy/paste the layer and leave the new one out of the legend. Or you can convert the legend to graphics and delete the legend elements manually.

Comment: I have never converted a legend to a graphic but that does sound like it might work. Due to time constraints I went ahead and separated the two symbols into two features and just removed one from the legend. Thank you for your answer, I will try what you suggested just the same to see how well it works for this recurring situation.

Comment: Its going to be much cleaner in the future to simply use two layers to symbolize and then remove one layer from the legend. Converting legends to graphics is a nightmare if anything is going to change after you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a dot density analysis instead.

In order to do something like that you would first have to preform the [dot density process](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-dot-density-layers.htm). After that is done you would need to export these dots as a point shapefile, while at the same time preserving the second value.

[image]

Comment: This is for leasehold boundaries. I have overlapping ownership and need to show the same area having multiple owners. For example I am using solid blue for one owner then a crosshatch for another; this allows you to see 2 different colors for one section. In the legend I only want to show one color/symbol for each owner instead of the same ownership description shown twice. So not sure if dot density would apply. Thank you for your answer!